# select row with most information in conjunction with PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row, partitioning

I have a table with duplicates and I want to partition by the ID and select only the row with the most information (where the most fields contain values).

```
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| ID | Name | City |  Zip  | Address | Phone |  
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Joe  |      |       |         |       |  
|  1 | Joe  | DC   | 11111 |         |       |  
| 2  | Pete | NY   |       |         |       |  
|  2 | Pete | NY   | 10000 |         | 202-  |  
|  3 | Max  |      |       |         |       |  
| 3  | Max  |      |       |         |       |  
|  4 | Sean | MIA  |       |         |       |  
|  4 | Sean | MIA  |       | 1 blvd  |       |  
|  4 | Sean |      | 12345 |         | 305-  |  
|    |      |      |       |         |       |  
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

This is my goal:

```
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| ID | Name | City |  Zip  | Address | Phone | Row_num |
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|  1 | Joe  | DC   | 11111 |         |       |       1 |
|  2 | Pete | NY   | 10000 |         | 202-  |       1 |
| 3  | Max  |      |       |         |       |       1 |
|  4 | Sean | MIA  |       | 1 blvd  |       |       1 |
|    |      |      |       |         |       |         |
+----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

For Joe it is obvious that I want the second row with where the city and zip information is given. 
 
For Pete I also want to display the second record because it contains more information. 
 
For Max it doesn't matter what row I choose because both records have the same values. 
For Sean I can either take the second or third row because the second record has 3 fields which contain value (name, city, address) and the third record has also three filled fields (name, zip, phone). So It doesn't matter which record I want to select from Sean.

How can I partition my table and select the row with the most information about each person?

Comment: What logic applies to determine what is 'more' information, the length of the data in the field as expressed in bytes? If that's the case, you could have an expression that added up the binary-length of each column in the row, and then when you partition the records, select the row that has the maximum binary-length of the group

Comment: Would you care to add weights to the columns, e.g. all other things being equal a `Zip` beats a `Phone`?

Comment: Habo, no I there is no prioritization of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns are all strings, you can simplify the logic using `apply`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.id order by v.cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (select count(*)
            from (values (name), (city), (zip), (address), (phone)) v(col)
            where col is not null
           ) v(cnt)
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to adapt this for empty strings, you can change the `where` to `where col is not null and col <> ''`.

Comment: but what if they are not all strings?

Comment: @not_ur_avg_cookie Then maybe you could try my answer.  Did you bother?

Comment: `count( col )` would ignore NULLs, making the `where` clause unnecessary (unless it is modified to filter out empty strings).

Comment: @Habo . . . I had actually considered that but thought the `where` would be more transparent in its intentions.

Comment: works really well. I tried it out in various scenarios! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(10), city varchar(10));
insert into @t values
    (1, 'Joe', null)  
  , (1, 'Joe', 'DC') 
  , (2, 'Pete', 'NY')
  , (2, null, 'NY')  
  , (3, null, 'TX') 
  , (5, 'Harry', null) 
  , (4, null, null);
select * 
from ( select * 
            , case when name is null then 0 else 1 end  
            + case when city is null then 0 else 1 end
              as rowCnt 
            , row_number() over (partition by id order by case when name is null then 0 else 1 end  
                                                        + case when city is null then 0 else 1 end desc) as rn
       from @t
     ) tt   
where tt.rn = 1 
order by tt.id

id          name       city       rowCnt      rn
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------
1           Joe        DC         2           1
2           Pete       NY         2           1
3           NULL       TX         1           1
4           NULL       NULL       0           1
5           Harry      NULL       1           1
```

Comment: I did try it out. I would even modify it and put a isnull function around all columns in the case statement to unify all empty fields and fields with null values. However, if you have more columns you need to add a case statement for each column. This makes this query gigantic and it slows down the machine.

Comment: Well do you have something better?

Comment: I mean no. This is why I was asking. I really appreciate your answer tho so don't get me wrong, please!